# How do I find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}+i,\sqrt{3}+i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

I can see that $[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and that each of $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+i):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i):\mathbb{Q}]$ is $4$. This implies that $4|[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}+i,\sqrt{3}+i):\mathbb{Q}]$ and that $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}+i,\sqrt{3}+i):\mathbb{Q}]\leq 32$, but as far as finding the basis itself, I'm lost.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that your field is just $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2} + i,\sqrt{3} + i) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. It can be shown that $i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 8$. Consider the tower of fields
$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},i).$$
You can use the tower law to find a basis: If $F \subset K \subset L$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ is an $F$-basis of $K$ and $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m$ is a $K$-basis of $L$, then $\{\alpha_i\beta_j : 1 \leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq m\}$ is an $F$-basis of $L$.

Comment: How can I prove your first statement that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2} + i,\sqrt{3} + i) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: @los_mathematiker Just prove both inclusions - they are both easy.